# Django how to get all items with ForeignKey reference

Tags: sql, django, model

I don't know, which way in Django to do something like this:

```
autors = Autor.objects.all().filter(book.autor=<value>)
```

Please can someone open my eyes?

Thanks for every help!

greatz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on [queryset filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) can definitely help you

```
autors = Autor.objects.filter(book__autor=<value>)
```

You would use `__` to filter based on foreign key attributes.